# Identifying stress in financial stress index constructed using PCA using Hodrick-Prescott filter

Tags: time-series, pca, finance, signal-processing

I am reading:

https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/128519/1/ewp-356.pdf

The footnote on page 19 says:

The trend was derived using the Hodrick-Prescott method where the smoothing parameter λ is set to 1,600. Since
the first two principal component account for about half of variation, half point 0.5 was used as criteria to identify
financial stress episodes. Using one point rule as in t he variance-equal weights method might fail to capture
significant episodes of emerging market financial stress.

In other words, the author of this paragraph is saying that : Suppose we reduce the dimension of a data set by say for example 50% by doing a PCA and selecting number of components (in this case 2)  which explain 50% of the variation , then we may say that the original series is "high" if the reduced dimensional index is above .5 standard deviations above the "trend" as measured by the Hodrick Prescott filter.  If we use ***one*** standard deviation above the trend we will miss out important stress events since the reduced dimension data sets varies less than the original dataset.

My ***question*** is : should we be doing .5 or $\sqrt{.5}$ standard deviations above the mean since in the square root of variance is the standard deviation.

***I try to write a precise query (with all steps) which I have regarding the above paragraph***:

Y is a financial stress index, ie. we are trying to make an index which is high when financial stress is high.

$ \hat{Y} = PC1 + PC2  $

where

$$ (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 ) / sum(\lambda_i) = .5 $$

ie. We are doing a PCA and approximating Y by the sum of PC1 and PC2 whose total variation is about 50 percent of the variation in Y.

We use the Hodrick-Prescott filter to estimate the trend in $\hat{Y} = PC1 + PC1$.

Here is am interesting question : How many standard deviations from it's trend must $\hat{Y}$ be in order for us to say that the original $Y$ is 1 standard deviation above it's trend ?

Solution:

$ \hat{Y} = PC1 + PC2 = my_{PC} = \lambda_{my_{PC}} \vec{unit.vector_{my_{PC}}}$

where $\lambda_{my_{PC}} = \sqrt{.5}$

which would ensure that $ var(\hat{Y}) = .5 * var(Y) $

When I run a Hodrick-Prescott filter on $\hat{Y}$  to estimate the trend in $\hat{Y}$ this trend could be:

1. ***Same*** as the trend in the original $Y$.
   Suppose the trend = mean, $Y$ and $\hat{Y}$ will have the same trend. Another intuitive example, the trend could be ***less than*** 50 percent variable than the variation in Y, then I guess the Hodrick Prescott filter will return the ***same*** answer regardless of whether I run it on $Y$ or $\hat{Y}$.
2. The trend in the $\hat{Y}$ could be ***less*** variable than the trend in the original $Y$, after all $\hat{Y}$ explains 50 percent of the variance in $Y$.

I do not know the answer to whether 1 or 2 is true.

Also another important question I have is that, if I run the Hodrick Prescott filter to estimate the trend, should I say Y is 1 standard deviation above the mean in case $\hat{Y}$ is .5 standard deviations above it's trend or  $\sqrt{.5}$ standard deviations above it's trend ?